# rails 5.2 Webpacker asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack

Hi I have been having trouble with an application i started using the [jumpstart](https://github.com/excid3/jumpstart) template from gorails.

I am finding that my I am struggling to get my js to work. For this example( there are many) I will use trix editor.

I follow the instructions

Add trix-rails to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'trix-rails', require: 'trix'
```

Run bundle install and restart your server to make the files available through the pipeline.

Import Trix styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require trix
```

Require Trix Javascript magic in app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require trix
```

but i get a blank box like so

[image]

Its starting to kill my vibe. and I am sure its because i dont fully understand how the pipeline works now with webpacker.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@article) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :title %>
    <%= f.input :content, as: :trix_editor %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

any help would be appreciated. Because i am using webpacker should i be placing javascript and css somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, webpacker is not going through the asset pipeline. 
If you have a Rails 5.x project, you can use the asset pipeline (check your Rails version in the gemfile) next to webpacker.

With the same boilerplate I made it work by following these steps:

- add to gemfile as you did and `bundle install`
- `yarn add trix` in the command line
- add `@import "trix";` to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`
- and then, because of the yarn install you can import it into the 'new' javascript folder `app/javascript/packs/application.js` like so: `import 'trix'`

With the same html code, the editor now shoes perfectly fine for me :)

Comment: hi @Clara, thank you so to be clear in my app/javascript/application.js i am first require('trix') then import 'trix'... do i first have to install with yarn?

Comment: Import it into `application.js` as such: `import "trix"

Comment: awesome could you show me in your answer what the file would look like? then i can mark you correct after i test it

Comment: Sorry Joe, I got a bit mixed up with the asset pipeline and webpacker. If you have a rails 5 project, you can use the asset pipeline as it is explained in the gem documentation. I chang my answer accordingly.

Comment: no you were on the right path, because i am using the jumpstart template, it uses webpacker. I just need to know how to utilise webpacker as you first explained, i just needed to understand how to implement trix into it.

Comment: you can see in my question.. the above isnt working

Comment: the asset pipline will still work. both does, webpacker and the asset pipeline

Comment: Hi Joe, I tried it with the same boilerplate now and made it work. I edited my answer again, so you can follow the steps

Comment: hey clara, thank you so much.... I was playing around and found that I by using the old tags <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>, I could make it work but if i use the <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %> it wouldnt... I will try your way now... I really appreciate you and your efforts, your students are very lucky

Comment: Clara you are right.... Just one thing I got an error on yarn install trix, its now yarn add trix. You have changed my webpack life

Comment: Of course, fixed it and now we have a nice answer :)